# How to customize the freemarker expression?

Tags: java, freemarker, template-engine

How to customize the freemarker expression, the syntax like the following

```
<#if name?myExpr>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "customize"? What are you trying to achieve actually?

Comment: Yes."myExpr" isn't Freemarker builtin expression."myExpr" was achieved through my Class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with `?`. The point of the `?` operator is exactly that the function names come after it are reserved for the FreeMarker Template Language, so new functions can be added to new FreeMarker releases without breaking backward-compatibility.

You can, however, add functions that are called as `foo(param)`. I understand that people would prefer the postfix-call style (`param?foo`), but that has the compatibility issue mentioned. (I have also recommended `param?@foo` for this, but AFAIR the idea wasn't popular on the list.)

Comment: Related question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486619/invoke-java-method-with-parameters-from-freemarker.