# Invoke Java method with parameters from Freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker

The following FTL markup  works fine for me and calls getWidgets() in my server-side JiveActionSupport object:

```
<#list widgets! as widget>
  -- do something with widget.sku
</#list>
```

However, I really need an inner list that depends on a property of widget, something like this:

```
<#list widgets! as widget>
  <#list manufacturers(widget.sku)! as manufacturer>
  -- do something with manufacturer
  </#list>
</#list>
```

I have tried to implement the server-side code, as either:

```
public List<Manufacturer> getManufacturers(int sku);
public List<Manufacturer> getManufacturers(String sku);
```

But both result in 'Expression manufacturers is undefined at line 123'.

How can you pass parameters to methods of the current JiveActionSupport object?  Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like complexity that you should move out of the markup.
Determine the list of manufacturers in the controller (or whatever is invoking the template), and expose that list directly to the template. Keep the template simple.

Comment: Yup, I could certainly make it simpler but I'm still interested in how one invokes a method with parameters, for situations beyond this.  The article at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362343 suggests that it can be done but I cannot get the simplest example with an int or String parameter to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The thing that possibly confused you here is that `getFoo()` can be called as `foo`, but `getFoo(param)` can't be called as `foo(param)`, only as `getFoo(param)`. But this is just how JavaBeans work; `getFoo()` defines a JavaBean property, while `getFoo(params)` doesn't.

Anyway, if `getManufacturers` is the method of the data-model (root) object, then (assuming proper object wrapping) you should be able to call it as `getManufacturers(param)`. You don't need to start it with `action.` in principle.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful.  I have tried this with getManufacturers(string) but that still results in the undefined expression error.  In my case at least, it only works if I use action.getManufacturers(string).  Perhaps there's something additionally wrong with the data model object.  Also if I grep my Jive installation, I find a lot of references to "action.getXYZ()" in its FTL files suggesting that it needs to prefix with action. too, at least in some situations.

Comment: We had to know how the data-model is built, or what is it anyway. It's probably not the same object as the `action` object based on what you say.

Answer (score 4):

In general, it looks as if you need to do this as follows:

```
<#list action.getManufacturers("123")! as manufacturer>
  -- do something with manufacturer
</#list>
```

In particular, while you can use *things* in FTL to invoke the server-side method *getThings()*, you need to use *action.getThing("123")* to invoke the server-side method *getThing(String)*.